# Websocket running in asyncio loop inside a thread disconnects immediately

Tags: websocket, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I'm developing an application that uses multiple threads for various communication channels. One of them is websocket for which I'm using asyncio loop to run:

```
class Rotator():
    def __init__(self):
        # some irrelevant stuff here...
        self._readThread = threading.Thread(target=self._ReadThread, daemon=True)
        self._usbThread = threading.Thread(target=self._UsbThread, daemon=True)
        self._webThread = threading.Thread(target=self._WebThread, daemon=True)
        self._socketThread = threading.Thread(target=self._SocketThread, daemon=True)
        self.InitializeRotator()

    def InitializeRotator(self):
        # some more irrelevant stuff here
        self._readThread.start()
        self._usbThread.start()
        self._webThread.start()
        self._socketThread.start()

    # not including _ReadThread() and _UsbThread() as they are irrelevant in this context

    def _WebThread(self): # including _WebThread() as illustration
        handler_object = server.WebHttpRequestHandler
        _httpServer = socketserver.TCPServer(("",self.webPort), handler_object)
        _httpServer.serve_forever()

    async def ws_handler(websocket, path):
        data = await websocket.recv()
        reply = f"Data recieved as:  {data}!"
        await websocket.send(reply)

    def _SocketThread(self):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        start_server = websockets.serve(self.ws_handler, str(self.DHCPIP), 8000)

        loop.run_until_complete(start_server)
        loop.run_forever()
```

The frontend JS code that communicates with this is:

```
    var ws;
    
    function startWebsocket() {
        ws = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.200.76:8000')

        ws.onopen = function(e){
            console.log('Connection established')
            ws.send('Connection established')
        }

        ws.onmessage = function(e){
            console.log('websocket message event:', e)
        }

        ws.onclose = function(){
            // connection closed, discard old websocket and create a new one in 5s
            console.log('Connection lost, will reconnect in 5s...')
            ws = null
            setTimeout(startWebsocket, 5000)
        }
    }

    startWebsocket();
```

The web page that contains the frontend is served by the server run by _WebThread(). The issue is that the connection is being closed immediately after being established. I'm assuming the issue is caused by some conflict in the asyncio/thread combination, because I tested the server side code on its own and it worked like a charm. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you see something in the browser console or in the websocket entry in the network tab of the dev tools?

Comment: @AntonMihaylov in the console I see the message `'Connection established'` , followed immediately by the `'Connection lost, will reconnect in 5s...'` one. In the WS entry in the Network tab of the browser I see a list of all the reconnection attempts, all with status code 101 (Switching protocols)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated your example and managed to fix it using two changes:

1. ws_handler is missing the `self` parameter. Since it's an instance method, the instance itself will be passed as the first parameter. The actual websocket object will be the second one.
2. in ws_handler I added a `while True` loop. I followed the example in the docs here https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro/tutorial1.html#bootstrap-the-server

final result:

```py
    async def ws_handler(self, websocket, path):
        while True:
            data = await websocket.recv()
            reply = f"Data recieved as:  {data}!"
            await websocket.send(reply)
```

Other changed that I made were to use 8000 as a port for the http server, 8001 for the websocket server and 'localhost' instead of 192.168.200.76. But I'm pretty sure that's not relevant